# I'm confused. Why was this person's question flagged as "Off Topic"?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, on-hold

The following question (not by me) was put on hold:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30004061/converting-minutes-and-hours-into-text-representations-in-java

And the cited reason was "off-topic":

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack
>   Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.
>   Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve
>   it.

Was this a mistake? The user made no request for *"a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource"*.  The user was asking about converting numbers to words.

Comment: Part of the question was "if there is already a class for this it would help a lot". That most likely caused people to believe that it was looking for an off-site resource.

Comment: He's wondering if a java class could potentially solve his problem. Asking about a java class is not asking about an off-site resource.  This really seems like 1 person misread what the person was saying, and a few others did the knee-jerk piling on.

Comment: *"Asking about a java class is not asking about an off-site resource"* - given that Stack Overflow is **not** Java's documentation site: *yes, it is*.

Comment: I'm sorry @jonrsharpe, but that's nonsense.  There are many valid questions on how to do things on SO over the years that ask for particular facilities within various platforms/languages.

Comment: The OP was just asking someone to go and find existing code for them! The question showed no research effort whatsoever and certainly should have been put on hold, whether that was the *most* appropriate close reason or not. Your answer is link-only; take that out and all it says is *"you could write code to do this"* (no kidding!) *"valid questions... over the years"* is not a good argument; times change. Also, you'd probably get a better response to *"I disagree because..."* than *"that's nonsense"*; [be nice](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice).

Comment: No, the OP was clearly more than willing to write it himself.  Look at the comments, and look at his original question.

Comment: In any case, a moderator (or someone) ***thankfully*** reversed the [on hold], so hopefully we're done with this nonsense.

Comment: And right now 2 of the 3 answers link to an external resource. Wonderful.

Comment: @ivarni, That's a complaint of the answers, ***NOT*** of the question.  I'm not contesting that the answers could be better if they included content *of* the links instead of just the links.

Answer (score 9):

Here's the original question:

> I've tried looking this up but was unsuccessful. I'm using the SimpleDateFormat and Date class to get the current time. In the watch face I am developing for Android wear requires the text version of the time. For example, 8:30 would be "eight" and "thirty", 9:21 would be "nine" for the hour and "twenty one" for the minute. I'm not sure if this is possible without doing without writing the code manually, or if there is already a class for this it would help a lot. Please let me know if this is possible, thanks :)

That tells us what the OP is trying to do, but didn't show what they tried or where they're stuck. It's explicitly asking "if there is already a class for this" which is probably what attracted close votes to begin with. They then went on to edit the question with a solution (?) so the question probably should be closed. It's really not very high-quality, and is unlikely to help other people in its current state.

Comment: The stated reason was this: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow".  Despite whatever misgivings you have about the OP's qeustion formation, the stated reason ***does not apply to his question***.  He's asking about converting time numbers to words.  That's all he was asking.

Comment: @tgm1024 1. I didn't vote to close the question, as you can see. 2. Yes, the stated reason does apply to the question. Most of that question isn't a question at all.

Comment: Consider: If a person is unable to find a java built-in utility to do something, does that mean he can't ask if there's a java class for it?

Comment: I never said you voted to close the question.

Comment: @tgm1024 Yes, that's what it means. You don't just drop off your requirements at Stack Overflow. You do your own research.

Comment: "You don't just drp off your requirements at Stack Overflow".  (?????)  HOW DID HE DO THAT?  He was very clearly willing to do this by hand.  He was also very clearly asking if it existed in Java already.  How on EARTH is this wrong?  This is ***precisely*** where SO has gone completely off the deep end with pedantry.

Comment: Had there been a facility in Java to convert numerical representations into their corresponding words, I would have loved to have known about it.  I've been using java since 1996 and the facilities added from rev to rev ***STILL*** catch me by surprise.

Comment: @tgm1024 No, that wasn't clear at all from the original post. He posted his requirements and literally nothing else. He then came back later and posted a partial solution as an edit to the question instead of an answer. This is not a good question.

Comment: It's also closed for a reason that does not apply.  He did not ask for an offsite resource or tool or book or or or....  He's asking about whether a specific ability is included in the Java language, and that is most definitely an apt question for StackOverflow.

Comment: @tgm1024 It didn't say anything about a Java built-in utility. It sounded like the OP was looking for source code or a library that could be found somewhere on the internet, which **is** looking for an off-site resource. Or at least people could interpret it that way, I was not part of the close vote.

Comment: And saying that he posted his requirements and nothing else is nonsense----he stated that he could write this by hand.  Seriously, you want to ban all forms of "I could code this by hand but does it exist in the language"?

Comment: So you'd prefer that he didn't say "I'm not sure if this is possible without doing without writing the code manually, or if there is already a class for this it would help a lot." but instead said "I'm not sure if this is possible without doing without writing the code manually, or if there is already a ***JAVA*** class for this it would help a lot." ?????  We're losing sight of what's important here.

Comment: @tgm1024 Are we reading the same question? I only see requirements and a very vague description of what he's using. There was no code in the original question.

Comment: (?)  His description was exacting: he's converting time numbers to words.  Again, we're losing sight of what's important here.  We need to get ***out*** of the business of making people feel bad for no reason.

Comment: He doesn't need to go into more detail because that's not pertinent to what he's asking.  His question was clear to me, and to the others who upvoted his question.

Comment: @tgm1024 well, if they feel bad is their prerogative. We shouldn't go tiptoeing just to be careful we don't hurt someone's feeling. The question just doesn't meet Stack Overflow quality standards and isn't within the scope of expertise Stack Overflow aims to offer. That's all there is. If they feel bad or not, that's not our interest.

Comment: Then I'm sorry, but you've lost track of how to help people.  Heck, you've even lost track of the greater good.  There is NO GOOD from chastising someone for asking if there's a built-in solution for something, and he certainly didn't ask what the flaggers said he did.  I'm sorry, but StackOverflow didn't use to be like this.  Good grief, [Michael Richter was right](http://michael.richter.name/blogs/why-i-no-longer-contribute-to-stackoverflow)

Comment: @tgm1024 Nobody is chastising anyone.

Comment: @tgm1024: It seems rather rude to ask people to explain why something was done and then attack them for attempting to do so. Perhaps you should step away from the keyboard for a few minutes, calm yourself, and take a different approach here. Being abusive isn't going to get you very far. (And yes, I guess I am lightly chastising you for being personally insulting toward Bill the Lizard, who is simply expressing his opinion and has done nothing to deserve comments that personally insult him like "you've lost track". I'm afraid you've lost track of how to control your emotions here.)

Comment: I am not able to understand how it is off site . He is asking asking for existing java class which include every class in jdk also. He may have poor choice of words but he is genuinely asking for java api methods.

Comment: Fact is, we are not here as teachers, we are not a tutoring site - this site is meant to be a repository of knowledge.

Comment: Fact is @KenWhite, that a high road attempt like yours ***IS*** an attack.  Mine is a defense of someone else who is innocently asking about Java API.  And somehow it's more important at SO to hold onto pedantry in some kind of absurd ego driven power play.  THE GUY WAS ASKING A SENSIBLE JAVA QUESTION, and NOTHING in the cited reason applied.

Comment: "not here as teachers, this site is meant to be a repository of knowledge".  WHERE is the knowledge gained by putting a question on hold and citing reasons that don't apply?  There is certainly *more knowledge* to be gained by simply telling him, "no, the java IDE doesn't have such a facility."

Comment: @Panther, YES, that's precisely what I'm trying to drive at here.  Gentlemen, instead of stubbornly holding to a pedantic way of treating people, consider reading what someone says and ***defaulting*** to the idea that it's a properly formed question.  Instead of this pile-on approach with a default bannering words to the effect of "this question doesn't belong".

Comment: Well, thankfully a moderator (or someone) reversed the [on hold] for that question.  Good.  We're done here.